# Loki API - start and end params

Tags: grafana-loki

I want to get logs using loki API. But even after checking the official documentation, I still don't know how.

What I want is to specify `start` and `end` parameters in `loki/api/v1/query_range`, but I don't know what to put in those parameters.

How does this time `2023-08-14 10:09:16.035` become like this `1691975356035337780`?

I tried like this:

```
https://Mydomain/loki/api/v1/query_range?query={app=test}&start=20230813&end=20230814
```

and also tried putting the millisecond value of the unix time, but it didn't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How does this time become `1691975356035337780`?

It's Unix timestamp in nanoseconds. Loki supports timestamps in a couple of formats: Unix timestamp in seconds, Unix timestamp in nanoseconds, RFC3339 and RFC3339Nano.

Excerpt from [official documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/api/#timestamp-formats) on how they are interpreted:

> The API accepts several formats for timestamps. An integer with ten or fewer digits is interpreted as a Unix timestamp in seconds. More than ten digits are interpreted as a Unix timestamp in nanoseconds. A floating point number is a Unix timestamp with fractions of a second.
>
> The timestamps can also be written in `RFC3339` and `RFC3339Nano` format, as supported by Go’s [time package](https://pkg.go.dev/time).

Based on this your attempt with `...&start=20230813&end=20230814` was interpreted as request for data between Aug 23 1970 03:40:13 and Aug 23 1970 03:40:14.

You should use either `...&start=2023-08-13T00:00:00Z00:00&end=2023-08-14T00:00:00Z00:00` or `...&start=1691884800&end=1691971200` (or their "nano" counterparts.

> I also tried putting the millisecond value of the unix time, but it didn't work...

Milliseconds aren't supported. Only seconds or nanoseconds.

---

For additional information on endpoints and their parameters, please reference this documentation: [`query`](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/api/#query-loki), [`query_range`](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/api/#query-loki-over-a-range-of-time)

Comment: for the UTC timestamp, this is the correct format accepted by Loki: 2023-08-13T00:00:00Z instead of the one mentioned above: 2023-08-13T00:00:00Z00:00